# Kibana doesn't show results on tile map

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4, geohashing

I have approximately 3300 documents with geo_point typed field filled.
When I try to visualize my documents on the tile map, kibana says "no results found".

I've already tried putting coordinates as:
 - geohash in string
 - [lon, lat] array
 - object with "lat" and "lon" properties
 - string "lat,lon"

All these ways of setting geo_point are allowed according to [ES docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-geo-point-type.html).
Kibana detects this field as geo_point (there is a globe icon near field name), but nothing shows up on tile map.

What's wrong with me?

I'm using Kibana 4.2, elasticsearch 2.0.0

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393819/kibana-4-detects-geodata-but-doesnt-display-any-results-on-the-map

Answer (score 2):

I've managed it.

It was happening because I had my geo_point typed field inside of the field with "type": "nested" parameter.

I've changed this outer field to "dynamic": "true" and now I can visualize my locations!

Comment: I was able to have a nested geo_point by removing the "type": "nested"  from the mapping. No "dynamic":"true" needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to have a nested geo_point by removing the "type": "nested"  from the mapping. No "dynamic":"true" needed. My mapping looks like this:

```
"mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "_all": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "_ttl": {
                "enabled": true,
                "default": "12m"
            },
            "dynamic_templates": [{
                "string_fields": {
                    "match": "*",
                    "match_mapping_type": "string",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "analyzed",
                        "omit_norms": true,
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }],
            "properties": {
                "@version": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "user_data": {
                    "properties": {
                        "user_geolocation": {
                            "properties": {
                                "location": {
                                    "type": "geo_point"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```